# How do I project id as something else with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my `Node.js` microservice, I use `Mongoose` to get a document out from my mongoDB. The document has many properties but i only want to project 3 of them:

I want to project the '_id' as 'id', then I want to project the 'name' and 'description'. I try to do it like this:

```
const group = await Groups.findOne(
    { 'orgId': Number(orgId), '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id) },
    {'id': '$_id', 'name': 1, 'description': 1}
);
```

But this is what it returns:

```
{
    "_id": "63c006b7f1f085f7d8a683ff",
    "name": "TestGroup",
    "description": "some description"
    "id": "63c006b7f1f085f7d8a683ff"
}
```

Comment: Just add `_id:0`next to your other project operator to remove `_id` from result

Comment: @Fourchette I've already tried. It does remove `_id` from the result however for some reason the value of `id` comes out as `null` in the result

Comment: Seems to work fine https://mongoplayground.net/p/AxjxnTGytud

Comment: @Fourchette you're right it works in the playground, so I'm very confused,  as to why it doesn't work in my service. The weird this is if I change `id: $_id` to `refId: $_id` it gives the following result: `{
  "name": "TestGroup",
  "refId": "63c006b7f1f085f7d8a683ff",
  "description": "some description",
  "id": null
}`

Comment: Notice that on the playground example @Fourchette added: `_id: 0`. This is removing the field from the result. You don't have it on your example

Comment: @nimrodserok Yes, I didn't have it in my example. But I added it to my code and it didn't help. The reason why it didn't help is because a contributor had added `groupSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
});` to the Groups model. So I just had to add `transform: (doc, ret) => { delete ret._id; }` and then instead of the suggested projection I can simply use `'name description'`. Works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove `_id` from your JSON output you can do this:

```js
new mongoose.Schema(modelSchema, {
    toJSON: { 
       virtuals: true,
       transform: (doc, ret) => { delete ret._id; }
    }
});
```